# Multiple Request Handling in java using concurrency api

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I have a server which can handle 1000 threads simultaneously.
So for handling the request, i implemented the producer consumer pattern in my code similar kind of servlet container.

1. At a time, we can have more than 3000 request so for handling this
   scenario, what should be the queue size and why?
2. let's assume we have a queue size of 2000, then what should we do if
   we have 4000 request. how can we handle this scenario(easiest way is
   to discard the extra request but we need to handle each and every
   request)?
3. I want to generate 20 parallel thread just like jmeter does. How can
   i do that using java concurrency API.
4. In the above scenario, what type of ThreadPool should we need to
   utilize like CachedThreadPool or any other and why?

Comment: Thank you for making it presentable

Answer (score 0):

There are two dimensions of bounds to think about: one dimension is how many threads you can use (which is ultimately usually bounded by having enough memory for the corresponding thread stacks -- on a modern JVM the default is a megabyte of stack per thread so 1000 threads is a gigabyte of memory for thread stacks alone). The other dimension is the bounds on your work queue.

For request serving, you probably want a fixed size thread pool (sized according to [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law) for your workload) and a queue that can grow as needed. For a request-based server an unbounded queue probably has the best graceful degradation result, although you might want to experiment with a bounded queue and a load-shedding RejectedExecutionPolicy.

All of these options can be configured in [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) which is probably the implementation you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement "**To process each and every request**" you should consider using a Queue (just for suggestion ActiveMQ, it can be any queue implementation).
Put every incoming request into queue and have a thread pool of consumers to consume data from queue. In this way you can grantee that every request is getting processed and your application can scale without changing any stuff.